# tar: option requires an argument -- 'f'

Tags: pipe, tar

I am trying to download content by following this tutorial.  But when I use the following code from the tutorial:

```
curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=simple | tar -xzvf
```

I get the following error:

```
tar: option requires an argument -- 'f'
```

**How can I resolve this error to successfully download the content from the link?**

Here is the complete terminal output on CentOS 7:

```
[user@localhost ui]$ curl https://start.spring.io/starter.tgz -d style=web -d name=simple | tar -xzvf
tar: option requires an argument -- 'f'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 10 49930    9  4976  100    21   6989     29  0:00:07 --:--:--  0:00:07  6988
curl: (23) Failed writing body (489 != 1369)

[user@localhost ui]$
```

Comment: You might suggest back to the author of the tutorial that they're missing a dash :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> tar: option requires an argument -- 'f'

This gives it away -- tar's 'f' flag specifies the file to read or create. Since you were piping a (compressed) tar file in from curl, you just needed to tell tar that the "file" to read was stdin with a dash `-` at the end:

```bash
curl ... | tar -xzvf -
```